# VB.Net Split string after certain words

Tags: vb.net, string, split, keyword

I'm struggling to find a solution to my small problem in *VB.Net*.

I basically have a string originally from an XML which I need to insert a new line (chr(13) after certain words.

So for example if my string is;

```
TAF AMD EGNM 171734Z 1718/1818 16010KT 9999 BKN018 TEMPO 1718/1803 8000 -RA BKN010 PROB30 TEMPO 1718/1724 4000 RADZ BKN006 PROB40 TEMPO 1800/1809 BKN005 PROB40 TEMPO 1809/1818 6000 SHRA BKN010 BKN020TCU BECMG 1810/1813 23010KT
```

I need it to look like this;

```
TAF AMD EGNM 171734Z 1718/1818 16010KT 9999 BKN018 
     TEMPO 1718/1803 8000 -RA BKN010 
     PROB30 
     TEMPO 1718/1724 4000 RADZ BKN006 
     PROB40 
     TEMPO 1800/1809 BKN005 
     PROB40 
     TEMPO 1809/1818 6000 SHRA BKN010 BKN020TCU 
     BECMG 1810/1813 23010KT
```

Keywords to split as you can see is `'TEMPO'`, `'PROB30'`, `'PROB40'` etc

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not something like `yourstring.Replace("TEMPO", "TEMPO\r\n")`

Comment: That would actually be yourstring.Replace("TEMPO", "\r\nTEMPO") but it's right, that should do.

Comment: The example suggests you want to split before certain words rather than after. Also, do you have a finite number of "words" that require a the new line (which is chr(10), btw).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but didn't work quite as I wanted it to.  The below answer has worked fine, thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim toReplace() = new String() {"TEMPO", "PROB30", "PROB40", (...)}

For Each word As String In toReplace
    value = value.Replace(word, Environment.NewLine & word)
Next
```

Comment: That works great, many thanks for your help, new it would be fairly simple.